# iOS memory management issue with properties

Tags: ios5

I have a class with the following set:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSMutableDictionary *details;           
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableDictionary *details;
```

I removed all unnecessary details for this question. In the implementation file I included `@synthesize details;`

I'm forwarding to this view from another view and in that class I'm getting a local dictionary:

```
NSMutableDictionary *getData = [responsestring JSONValue];
```

and I'm setting it to the mutable dictionary in this class, and I tried in two ways. Both of which are mentioned below:

```
objMyVc.details = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:getData];
objMyVc.details = [getData retain];
```

Once I am in the MyViewController, the value details is ALWAYS null. Why is this so? Shouldn't the value be retained in this case?

**[EDIT]**

I can confirm that `getData` is not null because I have the following check:

```
if ([getData valueForKey:@"VALUE"]) {

}
```

It is within the `if` statement that I'm trying to assign the value to the details dictionary and forwarding to that `ViewController`. I also tried to copy like below:

```
objMyVc.details = getData;
```

Comment: Yes, it will be retained. Even more - you will have a leak since your property marked as retain and you call additional alloc or retain. Something is incorrect in another place. How you checked it for null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems correct. Have you checked whether getData is null? I would also check whether details is null immediately after you initialize it. I don't think that your problem has to do with retaining.

Comment: Yes, `getData` is for sure not null. Since I have an if statement right before hand to confirm the same.

Comment: Also, I have an `NSLog` statement to output its value.